# change size of column in database through ( APACHE ISIS)

Tags: java, wicket, jdo, datanucleus

I have a program in APACHE ISIS  that store message (string). However, I noticed that the size of message in database is 255. SO when i goes to store message with more than 255 character, 
It seem like

**javax.jdo.JDOFatalUserException**

Attempt to store value "Instance Variables (Non-Static Fields) Technically speaking, objects store their individual states in "non-static fields", that is, fields declared without the static keyword. Non-static fields are also known as instance variables because their values are unique to each instance of a class (to each object, in other words); the currentSpeed of one bicycle is independent from the currentSpeed of another. Class Variables (Static Fields) A class variable is any field declared with the static modifier; this tells the compiler that there is exactly one copy of this variable in existence, regardless of how many times the class has been instantiated. A field defining the number of gears for a particular kind of bicycle could be marked as static since conceptually the same number of gears will apply to all instances. The code static int numGears = 6; would create such a static field. Additionally, the keyword final could be added to indicate that the number of gears will never change. Local Variables Similar to how an object stores its state in fields, a method will often store its temporary state in local variables. The syntax for declaring a local variable is similar to declaring a field (for example, int count = 0;). There is no special keyword designating a variable as local; that determination comes entirely from the location in which the variable is declared — wh" in column "`MESSAGE`" that has maximum length of 255. Please correct your data!

```
    private  String message;
@MemberOrder(sequence="3")

@MaxLength(5000)

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}
public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}
```

please guys suggest me for  store data more than 5000 character.
Thank you

Comment: I have tried @Column(length=Integer.MAX_VALUE) and it seems error when run that program . its says that variable  is too big for jdbc , have to change into text or blob variable.

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on your database, I think.

Some databases are limited to 255 chars, though I know of some, such as MS SQL Server and Sybase, that will support columns more than that.  On MS SQL, for example, the following runs fine:

```
create table t1(a char(8000))
```

Try experimenting to find out what the limit is on the database you are using.

When you do figure that out, you will need to configure both JDO and Isis to tell them about the max length.  For JDO, use `@javax.jdo.annotations.Column(length=x)`; for Isis, use `@MaxLength(x)`.

for example:

```
@javax.jdo.annotations.Column(length=1000)
@MaxLength(1000)
public String getDescription() { ... }
```

If your database is limited to char columns of only 255 chars, and you use a different database, then the only other option is to use Isis' `Clob` class.

---

Related to this, I've just raised (and implemented) [ISIS-557](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ISIS-557), so that Isis automatically infers `@MaxLength` if the `@JDO Column(length=...)` is present.

Comment: Is there any solution for taking unlimited length?

Comment: You can use an org.apache.isis.applib.value.Blob (basically a wrapper around a byte[] array plus a mime-type and name)